# What should I do about a computer?

Tags: game-design

Hello my name is Joseph I'm trying to figure out what kinda of computer I should use for game development not gaming. Or should I build one and if I have to build one what should I use? Thank you

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Basically, you can develop games on every decent machine, I'm using an Asus laptop. As long as you have a decent graphics card that supports modern opengl versions I see no problem. I'll look more into development enviroment, for example I find it more easy to get started with development on unix based os than windows(I've tried both and apt/homebrew makes it really easy..unless you're choosing C#). Other than that, you're good to go!

Comment: Downvoted for answering an offtopic question with bad advice (unix & opengl are definitely nowhere near the most important things to have in game dev) + unnecessary brand promotion.

Comment: So what do you have in mind in your eyes of a great $1000 game development PC. I'm talking about the best processer, graphics card and mother board etc...

Comment: Also running not unity. Running unreal.